# Declare all Methods of inherited interface within interface?

Tags: c#, c, class

Do you need to redeclare all methods declared in the inherited interface in a derived interface?

**Example:**

```
public interface IBoo
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public interface IFoo : IBoo
{
    string SayHello();
}
```

Or would I have to do this:-

```
public interface IFoo : IBoo
{
    void DoSomething();

    string SayHello();
}
```

Comment: no need modifiers in interface and braces too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you need to redeclare all methods declared in the inherited
>   interface in your interface?

No. Actually this is the concept of inheritance. All the methods that are declared in the base interface will be inherited to the derived.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying this, I can accept your answer in 10

Comment: @AngelaMarie-Daley you welcome. I am glad that I hepled.